# Bootstrap Changing Existing CSS To Elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have just recently added links and scripts of Bootstrap **v4.5** into my project and noticed that by default it changes all of the text, buttons and styling I have previously done.

I added an bootstrap alert for my authentication however I do not want Bootstrap changing all of my CSS that I have implemented to it's default Bootstrap look.

Is there a way for Bootstrap to not alter the pre HTML and CSS I have created. I am only interested in using the Bootstrap elements I manually include such as the alerts and widgets.

Help is much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Isn't the whole point of Bootstrap to use their responsive CSS?

Comment: I mean the reason I am using it is for their nice components. I don't want it touching my CSS so i was curious if there is a way to disable there pre-font and text when adding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put link to your custom script and CSS below the links of bootstrap. The bootstrap CSS will get overridden.

PS: You can also download the customized bootstrap files according to just what you need, check this [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/)

Comment: I am using Angular's framework so each component has its designated CSS file. I configured and downloaded the Bootstrap files and put it in the src folder of my project. Will that do the trick?

Comment: Is there any .min.css file that got generated? If yes then you just need to import that and .min.js one, that would work

Comment: I just downloaded the file and checked, you need to import bootstrap.min.css from CSS folder and bootstrap.min.js from js folder in order to get your bootstrap working, hope this helps

Comment: Perfect, I will do that now and let you know

Comment: Do i need to npm install bootstrap and then import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';?

Comment: No, you just need to import the js file using the script tag (with proper file path) and link tag to import CSS file in your HTML file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218310/discussion-between-nikhil-singh-and-zain).